# Inetd and Xinetd: which is running?

Tags: ps, xinetd, inetd

I'm studying for the first LPIC exam. In a quiz, I've found this question:

> How can you tell whether your system is using inetd or xinetd as a super server?

And the right answer should be:

> Type `ps ax | grep inetd`, and examine the output for signs of inetd (or xinetd).

In my desktop (Fedora 21), this is the output of both cases:

```
15844 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto inetd

15848 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto xinetd
```

How should I tell which one is running, if one is running at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost certainly `xinetd` since regular `inetd` is older than dirt but you can check the RPM database:

```
[root@xxx01 ~]# rpm -qa xinetd
xinetd-2.3.14-39.el6_4.x86_64
[root@xxx01 ~]# rpm -qa inetd
[root@xxx01 ~]#
```

For your commands you can probably just start the xinetd service to get the commands to work (since one isn't running it looks like).

Also, probably a better command to run than `ps ax | grep <some binary>` is to just use `-C` for example:

```
[root@xxx01 ~]# ps -C xinetd
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1823 ?        00:00:00 xinetd
[root@xxx01 ~]#
```

Which eliminates extra output like you saw if you just `grep` the output of `ps`.

Answer (score 3):

The process you found running the command

```
ps ax | grep inetd
```

is the grep process itself, **no (x)inetd server is running**.

Answer (score 1):

These answers are distribution specific, but you are taking a quiz about administering a machine that you didn't configure.  You have no idea whether or not xinetd was renamed to act more like the traditional inetd.  Querying a package database may not do any good.  The best thing to do is to learn about each program so that you can distinguish between them.

I prefer to use `ldd` on the executables to determine the libraries that are linked to it.  With `xinetd`, you should see links to `libcrypt` and `libnsl`, 
but you will not find those two libs linked to the traditional `inetd`.